# how can I get image file with other form property's together in asp web api application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form in react application that include registration form.

this simple form have some input like title, content , etc and image.

so when I posted this form to server I couldn't see expected result:

[image]

as you know for posting this types of form we forced to set content-type: form-data in header of request.

my controller is:

```
    public class StoreRequest
    {
        public News news { get; set; }
        public int?[] categories { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase image { get; set; }
    };

    public class NewsController : ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        [JwtAuthentication]
        public IHttpActionResult Store(StoreRequest storeRequest)
        {
            return Ok(storeRequest);
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
```

and my model is:

```
    public class News : BaseModel
    {
        public News()
        {
            this.Category = new HashSet<Category>();
        }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "text")]
        public string content { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "bit")]
        public bool slide { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Staff")]
        public int staff_id { get; set; }
        public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> Category { get; set; }

    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

I'm beginner in C# specially in asp.

Comment: What is the problem? What is the expected result? What is the actual result you are getting?

Comment: i couldn't see title,content and image that send with request

Comment: News is a property object inside StoreRequest. So the form data name should follow the structure. Try sending with names such as `news.title`,  `news.content`, `news.slide` etc.

Comment: thanks for helping that's worked!
but how can I send only property without prefix like that in this issue?

Comment: You have the model class with nested structure so you need to use prefix. That's how the model binding happens. Or else you need to implement custom binding.

Comment: `public IHttpActionResult Store([Bind(Include = "title,content,slide,staff_id")] News news, int?[] categories, HttpPostedFileBase image)`
when I put News in parameter it self I faced with this error:
`Can't bind multiple parameters ('news' and 'image') to the request's content.`

Comment: so thanks that's helpful